# Javascript type conversion from String to number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, type-conversion

I have a problem where 20 character string converted the JS new NUMBER method.

```
var x4 = "22222222222222222222";
var x5 = "22222222222222222229";
Number(x4) 
parseInt(x5);
```

---

```
//Output
22222222222222220000
22222222222222220000
```

I was expecting to get the same value as the variable but in number format but I dont know whats wrong here. What is the best way to convert string to number will any number of digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript stores numbers as `Float64` (AKA [IEEE 754 double-precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64)).

The way an integer (full number, no fraction) is thus limited to 53 bits (52 explicit and 1 implicit).

Any number larger than that cannot be stored without losing precision; a compromise is being made and an approximation is stored instead.

In JS you can get this number (2 ^ 53 - 1) using `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`,
or if you'd like to check whether a number is a "safe integer" (No precision lost), `Number.isSafeInteger`.

There is no way to store numbers larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` natively in JS; However, depending on the task you have at hand, a larger number can be (costly) emulated using a `String`/`Array`/`Buffer`  with custom methods for performing mathematical operations, using a third-party library which does it for you, or, if you're using `NodeJS`, using a more efficient native (compiled) library for large numbers (Such as [bignum](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bignum)).

Update:
Since I posted the above answer, JavaScript has gained support for [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt), which is an arbitrarily-large *safe* integer format.
BigInt literals have also been added, which are just number with an `n` suffix. So for your example:

```js
const x4 = 22222222222222222222n;
const x5 = 22222222222222222229n;
```

no loss of precision here.
You can even go further; The following will work without losing precision at all, albeit very slowly:

```js
const veryLargeNumber = x4 ** 10000n;
// 29368033185714599045483110729334710018527698466665246504292741901594849999445152112231214493149844001358430994081988271893728711217783149614681323681876825053646556106638954761114573427277415424n
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt reply.

Comment: Sure.  You should consider selecting an answer as the accepted answer so that others in the future will have an easier time figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit to the size and precision of numbers in computers. Your problem is not fixable.

Further reading:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#IEEE_754:_floating_point_in_modern_computers

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754